# How can I get an instance of the parent class, the class that has initiated the current class when using object initialization?

Tags: c#, .net

I run in to this situation a lot. I'm finally seeking an answer on how I can do this. I understand that there are many ways, but most are dirty and include bad practices.

Just to make it clear, this is not asking for your opinion, it's asking how the majority of programmers deal with this kind of problem, pretty much any way possible that doesn't include really bad code.

I have a class called `CoreContext`, which I property inject new instances into the property's class names as show below. But what happens when I need the parent class that has initiated that class?

Say I need an instance of the `CoreContext` inside `SocketHandler` (`ClientSocketHandler`). How would I go about doing that? I feel like there's a really simple way, but I've never understood what that is.

Is there an even simple call stack I'm not seeing, or what? Note that I would prefer to do this, the way I am doing, Object initialization, and not assigning the properties later.

```
var coreContext = new CoreContext
{
    ConfigHandler = new JsonConfigHandler(),
    SocketHandler = new ClientSocketHandler(coreContext, IPAddress.Parse(""), 30),
    PacketProvider = new PacketProvider
    {
        Events = new Dictionary<short, Action<ICoreContext, IIncomingPacket>>
        {
            { IncomingPacketIds.AuthError, AuthErrorEvent.Process },
            { IncomingPacketIds.DeviceInformation, DeviceInformationEvent.Process },
            { IncomingPacketIds.AuthComplete, AuthCompleteEvent.Process },
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It looks to me that you'd be better off using constructor injection. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: Main reason was that it was just seen as the long way, when property injection was just much more simple. Even using constructor injection ( viewing this in my mind ) would land me in the same situation. If you're serious about this, it could help if you posted an answer with a code example.

Comment: If you mean initializing the class inside CoreContext's constructor ( I dont think you do, but just in-case ) and not just passing an instance of ClientSocketHandler into the constructor, then that's because I'm using dependency injection, so I couldn't do that.

Comment: Is there something wrong with assigning properties after object creation?
The code you posted cannot work, as you cannot pass reference to an object that you didn't initialize yet

Comment: It just seemed much cleaner to use object initialization, I still think there is maybe an even cleaner way that assigning after object creation, so I'll keep this question open.

Answer (score 2):

If you use constructor injection to pass a factory delegate to create the `ClientSocketHandler` you can circumvent this problem, but I'm not entirely sure that this is an improvement on simply setting the property after creation.

(Well, it *is* an improvement in that constructor injection is (IMO) better than propery injection.)

Anyway, here's an example in case it's of use to you.

Note the use of `context => new ClientSocketHandler(context)` to pass a factory delegate to the `CoreContext` constructor.

Then inside the `CoreContext` constructor you can pass `this` to the delegate.

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var coreContext = new CoreContext(context => new ClientSocketHandler(context))
            {
                ConfigHandler = new ConfigHandler()
            };
        }

        class ConfigHandler {}

        class ClientSocketHandler
        {
            readonly CoreContext _coreContext;

            public ClientSocketHandler(CoreContext coreContext)
            {
                _coreContext = coreContext;
            }
        }

        class CoreContext
        {
            public CoreContext(Func<CoreContext, ClientSocketHandler> socketHandlerFactory)
            {
                SocketHandler = socketHandlerFactory(this);
            }

            public ClientSocketHandler SocketHandler { get; private set; }
            public ConfigHandler ConfigHandler { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you use constructor injection, you can omit the setter for `SocketHandler`. Also note that you should be injecting via interfaces, but I've omitted that for brevity. I'm assuming that you don't want to `new` up an instance of `ClientSocketHandler` right there in the constructor!

Comment: Thank you, but I've decided to go with the property injection after the object has been created, as it wasn't that much different and just seemed like the cleanest way.

Comment: @fskdjwe Yes, I think that's what I would have gone with in this instance.